# Libsass-mave-plugin Multiple input and output directories

Tags: java, maven, sass

I have project with libsass-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.warmuuh</groupId>
    <artifactId>libsass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <inputPath>${basedir}/inputpath</inputPath>
        <outputPath>${basedir}/outputpath</outputPath>
        <generateSourceMap>false</generateSourceMap>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is it possible to specify more input and output paths without using maven profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use multiple executions. Remember to add a unique id for all of them.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.warmuuh</groupId>
    <artifactId>libsass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>firstId</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputPath>firstInputPath</inputPath>
                <outputPath>firstOutputPath</outputPath>
                <generateSourceMap>false</generateSourceMap>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>secondId</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputPath>secondInputPath</inputPath>
                <outputPath>secondOutputPath</outputPath>
                <generateSourceMap>false</generateSourceMap>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Does not work... When using multiple executions, it doesnt execute a single one of them.

Comment: /Edit: Ok, it seems only the call of the plugins maven goal compile (or watch) wont work anymore. If I build the whole project (or at least the generate-resources phase) then it works.